# Adding a value in the middle of an array on which cascading dropdown relies

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, cascadingdropdown

I may eventually have "Title 1E". This poses a problem as the corresponding Array below would, either, require me to create `["Title 1E", '8']` (which I wouldn't want to do) or create placeholders for all potential Title 1's (i.e. change to `["Title 2A", '100']` and create blank Title 1's 4-99), thereby making a very long menu filled with blank lines.

I'd manually insert the appropriate Array in the `subsubmenu`

If `submenu[0].push(4,1," "Title 1E", '4' ")` works, how can I change the following to `["Title 2A", '5']`

Hope it makes some sense. It's not all quite clear in my head.

```
(function() {
var submenu= [
        [   ["Title 1A", '0'],
            ["Title 1B", '1'],
            ["Title 1C", '2'],
            ["Title 1D", '3']
        ],

        [       ["Title 2A", '4'],
            ["Title 2B", '5'],
            ["Title 2C", '6'], 
            ["Title 2D", '7']  
        ],


];

//the Array below populates a sub-submenu when a selection is made above


var subsubmenu= [           

[   ["Issue 1A1", 'resonse1a1'],
        ["Issue 1A2", 'response1a2'],
        ["Issue 1A3", 'response1a3'],
        ["Issue 1A4", 'response1a4']
    ],

    [   ["Issue 1B1", 'resonse1b1'],
        ["Issue 1B2", 'resonse1b2'], 
        ["Issue 1B3", 'resonse1b3']
    ],


    [   ["Issue 1C1", 'resonse1c1']
    ],
        // etc...               
        ];
```

Comment: Seems complicated.  Maybe there's a way to create your menu that doesn't need those ids (or whatever they are), or maybe those ids don't need to be consecutive?

Comment: I've considered the same. Thanks, James.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually loop through the remaining items and increase the counter manually.
Like this

```
var submenu= [
        [   ["Title 1A", '0'],
            ["Title 1B", '1'],
            ["Title 1C", '2'],
            ["Title 1D", '3']
        ],

        [       ["Title 2A", '4'],
            ["Title 2B", '5'],
            ["Title 2C", '6'], 
            ["Title 2D", '7']  
        ],
];

var insert_at=0;
submenu[insert_at].push(["Title 1E", '4']);

// Since the item will be pushed at the last position in the corresponding array
// We need to increase the counter i.e. item at position 1 for all the following 
//items in the other arrays
for(i=insert_at+1;i<submenu.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<submenu[i].length;j++){
        submenu[i][j][1]++;
    }
}

// Now display that to confirm that it works ok
for(i=insert_at+1;i<submenu.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<submenu[i].length;j++){
        document.write(submenu[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/gunjankarun/zCjY5/

Comment: Though not sure if this will work, I'm checking this out. I think I may just may have to bite the bullet on this one and start with `["Title 1E", '8']`